# How can i make this lua file readable

Tags: lua

I don`t know how to decode this and what encoding is it .

```
     LuaR   “

         M @  @@  €A @ @  @À € C €   € À @  A    C @ @  A@ €@ @  A€ ÀA @ @  @@  €A @ @  @@  A @ @  A€ @A @ @  BÀ
```

If i open this file it showns those( ESC  NUL EOT EM .... ) instead of those symbols.

how to make this code readable thanks

Comment: This is Lua 5.2 bytecode.  You can [disassemble](https://lua-bytecode.github.io/) it or [decompile](https://www.google.com/search?q=lua+decompiler).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff ok i used disassembler and the code looks better , it looks (GETTABUP 1 0 -78   ..... JMP 0 25 ) how do i make it as source code so i can see functions and code clearly ? thx

Comment: To make a source code, you need a decompiler